# printing header in a log file using logback

Tags: logback

I want to print a header line on top of my log file generated using logback. My logback.xml contains following for this purpose :

```
<appender name="MyFile" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <File>path/to/logs/MyFile.log</File>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder">
      <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
      <fileHeader>Some header</fileHeader>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS}:%m%n</pattern>
      </layout>
    </encoder>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <fileNamePattern>path/to/logs/MyFile.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i</fileNamePattern>
    </rollingPolicy>
  </appender>
```

When new log file is created then header is printed on top as desired, but the problem is that if log file already exists, then on restarting tomcat, header is printed again. I need header to be printed only once in every log file.

I am new to logback. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There does not appear to be an option like that (i think it would have to be in the RollingFileAppender, because that's the place that detects the need for a new file.) Logback allows you to plug in your own appender (e.g. by sub-classing RollingFileAppender), but that might be over the top if you are new to logback.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `customPatternLayout` that extends `ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout` and you can override the `getFileHeader` and check whether the header already exists or not.

The code below worked for me:

```
public class CustomLogPatternLayout extends PatternLayout {

String filePath;
String header;

@Override
public String getFileHeader() {
    BufferedReader br;
    boolean constainsHeader = false;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
        String line = br.readLine();
        if (line != null) {
            constainsHeader = true;
        }
        br.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (constainsHeader) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return header;
    }

}
```